# error at dlsym(): ./dynlibrary: undefined symbol: method

Tags: c, gcc, dynamic-library, dlsym

I've got an issue I am not able to solve. Looked up everything I found so far.
My problem is, I create a dyn library in my program a want to dlopen it and dlsym a method out of that lib.

It seems that dlopen works but dlsym return me the error "**undefined symbol: method**"

where "**method**" is the name of the method I passed to dlsym.

Here is how I create the library:

```
execl("/usr/bin/gcc", "gcc", "-fPIC", "-Wall", "-g", "-c", "userinput.c", NULL);
```

and:

```
execl("/usr/bin/gcc", "gcc", "-ggdb3", "-shared", 
      "-Wl,-soname,libuserinput.so.1", "-o", "libuserinput.so.1.0",
  "userinput.o", "-lc", NULL);
```

This should work as there is a library after running my code.

I open the library like this:

```
static void *my_load_dyn (const char *lib) {
static void *handle;
handle = dlopen ("./libuserinput.so.1.0", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
if (handle == NULL) {
  printf ("error at dlopen(): %s\n", dlerror ());
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
return handle;
}

/* load func from dyn lib"*/
static void *my_load_func (void *handle, char *func) {
  void *funcptr = dlsym (handle, func);
  if (funcptr == NULL) {
    printf ("error at dlsym(): %s\n", dlerror ());
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return funcptr;
}
```

and call those functions like this:

```
void *libhandle;
void (*userMethod) (unsigned char *d);

libhandle = my_load_dyn(LIBUSERINPUT);
userMethod = my_load_func(libhandle, "testMethod");
(*userMethod)(d);
```

EDIT:
here is the code from the userinput.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void testMethod(unsigned char *d)
{
d[0] = 'Z';
}
```

It is generated in my programm and also compiled and linked in the running programm

Comment: Do `nm -D libuserinput.so.1.0 | grep testMethod`, what do you see?

Comment: nothing. Yes i should say that as well. I tried nm on that lib and the function name is not listet in the symbol table. sorry for not mentioning that. Now my problem is: Why is the Method not in there?

Comment: which `gcc` version are you using` which system is this on?

Comment: Not reproducible here. Show a self-contained test case.

Comment: maybe my forking in the rest code is wrong. If i compile/link my self it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

i can see two possible problems

- there's a problem in the code

  are you sure that you declare your `method` as a *public* function in `userinput.c`?

  e.g. if your method is declared `static`, then it won't be accessible from "outside".
  also there are other ways to *hide* functions from being seen outside of the library, but it's impossible to tell whether you are having that problem without seeing any code.
- your compilation/linking of the library is broken

  e.g. you seem to be linking in a header-file (`userinput.h`) into the resulting libray?

  i'd suggest to use a proper build system until the problem is solved, and switch to on-the-fly compilation later (e.g. using `make`)

Comment: i want to compile/link in my programm. Ill post the code of the userinput.c above in my question. Yes the userinput.h is not necessary. Ill remove that one

Comment: i'm suggesting that you *first* compile/link outside of your program, and once that works, move to doing it within your program. if you are having troubles with complicated setups, it's always a good idea to lower the complexity as a first step...

Comment: with compiling/linking myself it works. maybe my forking is bad